# ActiveX "Class doesn't support Automation"

Tags: javascript, .net, activex

This is my first attempt at an ActiveX control (and with this experience, it will be my last).  High level, when I try to use a method I get a console error which reads "Class doesn't support Automation".

I created a custom ActiveX control, installed it via a MSI, and am attempting to use it in an MVC application.  The interface is defined as:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
[Guid("7EC603C3-3FB9-4E8B-A5B8-4D5804511E15")]
public interface IPrinter
```

The concrete class:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[Guid("1F668100-532A-4077-BEDE-1610AF2CC6DF")]
[ProgId("AxControls.Printer")]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IPrinter))]
public class Printer: IPrinter, IObjectSafety
```

IObjectSafety interface and implementation:

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("34ABF5FA-1991-4D53-81BF-7DC7E3EFD8F6")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IObjectSafety
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid riid, out int pdwSupportedOptions, out int pdwEnabledOptions);

    [PreserveSig]
    int SetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid riid, int dwOptionSetMask, int dwEnabledOptions);
}

    public int GetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid riid, out int pdwSupportedOptions, out int pdwEnabledOptions)
    {
        const ObjectSafetyOptions options = ObjectSafetyOptions.INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CALLER | ObjectSafetyOptions.INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_DATA;
        pdwSupportedOptions = (int)options;
        pdwEnabledOptions = (int)options;

        return 0;
    }
    public int SetInterfaceSafetyOptions(ref Guid riid, int dwOptionSetMask, int dwEnabledOptions)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum ObjectSafetyOptions
    {
        INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CALLER = 0x00000001,
        INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_DATA = 0x00000002,
        INTERFACE_USES_DISPEX = 0x00000004,
        INTERFACE_USES_SECURITY_MANAGER = 0x00000008
    };
```

And my JavaScript:

```
var ax = new ActiveXObject("AxControls.Printer");
ax.Print(JSON.parse(data.obj), "NameOfPrinter");
```

The error occurs on the second JS line.  I'm using IE 11.  Stepping through the code it appears the Control loads properly.  If I alter the arguments to be invalid, I get a different message which leads me to believe that they are correct and are not the issue.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Not directly related but I found one issue with the Guid for IObjectSafety.  See link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423672/why-doesnt-implement-iobjectsafety-make-a-difference

Comment: In this case, it didn't like the fact that I was passing JSON for the first parameter of Print().  Instead, I passed data.obj (serialized obj) and then de-serialized in my control.  This corrected the behavior although I would still like to know exactly why this was an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was successfully able to use the ActiveX control by registering using the following command:

```
regasm /codebase [path to DLL]
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting this error on a remote machine, that I can not access. I found a few links mentioning that you need to re-registered a few DLLs, but not sure if they fix the issue. If you try this does it resolve your problem? [oracle docs, see issue 11821241](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17236_01/epm.1112/readme/ra_1112200_readme.html)

Run in Command Prompt:

```
regsvr32 msscript.ocx

regsvr32 dispex.dll

regsvr32 vbscript.dll

regsvr32 scrrun.dll

regsvr32 urlmon.dll
```